# Keeping only one column value of a 2 level Multi-index Pandas dataframe while ignoring NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        |     col1    |     col2     |     col3     |     col4     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
type    |             |cat1|cat2|cat3|cat1|cat2|cat3|cat1|cat2|cat3|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0       |ID1          |1   |NaN |1   |NaN |5   |5   |77  |77  |77  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |ID2          |4   |4   |NaN |6   |6   |6   |NaN |8   |8   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |ID3          |11  |11  |11  |9   |9   |NaN |24  |NaN |24  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:

*there are 4 upper columns, but only 3 of them have further subcategories.*

*The subcategories of each one should have the same value unless there is a NaN (which can be anywhere).*

I'd like to make the end dataframe look like this:

```
        |     col1    |     col2     |     col3     |     col4     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
0       |ID1          |       1      |       5      |      77      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |ID2          |       4      |       6      |      8       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2       |ID3          |       11     |       9      |      24      |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to reduce the extra level and just keep the value of the categories (since all the values are the same) without selecting the NaN's.

The end dataframe cannot have NaN's.

Initially I thought just slicing based on the first category would be enough, but because the NaN's can be anywhere, that does not work.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Does pandas have a way to print output like this? I'm just wondering how to read it in and if pandas can output it like this i can probably read it in nicely

Comment: @oppressionslayer I am not sure if it does to be honest. I inherited this data so I'm just trying to manipulate it into the correct form to put it on a database.

Comment: the last columns is `col3` or `col4`? I.e. you have duplicate column name `col3` in first level?

Comment: @AndyL., thanks for the catch. It is `col4`. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

the column `col1` is not a 1-level column. It has same 2 levels as other columns. its 2nd-level doesn't show anything because it is empty string. Try to run `df.columns` you see output as this

```
print(df.columns)

Out[637]:
MultiIndex([('col1',     ''),
            ('col2', 'cat1'),
            ('col2', 'cat2'),
            ('col2', 'cat3'),
            ('col3', 'cat1'),
            ('col3', 'cat2'),
            ('col3', 'cat3'),
            ('col4', 'cat1'),
            ('col4', 'cat2'),
            ('col4', 'cat3')],
           )
```

To get your desired output, you need `groupby` on `level=0` of columns (which is `axis=1`) and  and call `first`

```
df_out = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()

Out[644]:
     col1  col2  col3  col4
type
0     ID1     1   5.0  77.0
1     ID2     4   6.0   8.0
2     ID3    11   9.0  24.0
```